# `update-grub` command fails to set theme changes made in /etc/default/grub; may be particular to Kali

Tags: debian, kali-linux, grub, theme

**Tealdeer at the bottom.**

Hoo boy have I strugglebussed with this one. Pertinent details to follow, but first a quick overview of what's going on. No matter where I look, I cannot seem to find the file that controls what theme and BG image update-grub is pulling from. The number of symlinks, directories, grub config files, etc. that I have dug through in search of what is - on every other distro I've used - a basic, simple task, is simply stunning, and I'm at my wits' end.

I've tried to include everything pertinent I could think of here, but there's definitely some stuff I left out, in a futile attempt to keep this brief lol. If you need any more information, please ask, I'm happy to dig deep to resolve this stupid problem. It's a matter of principle at this point.

---

I am dual-booting Kali XFCE and Windows 11 on a Thinkpad T16 Gen 1. I have booted Mint Cinnamon, Mint XFCE, Manjaro KDE, and Arch with  KDE previously on this device, all on the same 100 GB partition, and Kali got a full reformat of the entire partition before being installed. No leftovers lingering around in here, or there shouldn't be, at least.

When I make changes to `/etc/default/grub`, some take (boot selection timeout, setting and saving the default as the last-booted option), but there is one that just refuses to acknowledge any change made in that file: GRUB_THEME. It just always loads the "Kali" theme, as you'll see laid out below.

The output of `/etc/default/grub` (at least, the important bits):

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=15
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_THEME=/boot/grub/themes/CyberRe/theme.txt
```

When I run `sudo update-grub', I get:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found theme: /boot/grub/themes/kali/theme.txt
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.0.0-kali6-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.0.0-kali6-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.0.0-kali3-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.0.0-kali3-amd64
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
```

If you'll notice, that ain't the right file for the theme I want to use, it's the leftover default setting. The same goes for the background image, but I'm hopeful that fixing theme will rectify that issue as well.

I have tried setting `GRUB_THEME=` to the same as above, but with quotation marks around it, no change. I've tried pointing it to `/usr/share/grub/themes/CyberRe/theme.txt` both with and without quotes: no change. I've also tried removing the /boot/grub/themes/kali directory and updating grub, hoping maybe it being missing would force it to look elsewhere, but instead it just loads no theme.

It's not just this install, either. My first go with installing Kali on this machine, I made the `/` directory only 30 GB, and then promptly filled it up with... toys. Instead of trying to fix/resize the partition and possibly breaking the Windows install (this *is* my daily driver for work, after all), I figured I'd just wipe and re-install, no longer separating `/` and `/home` directories. Before re-installing, I had this same exact issue then, as well. And I previously had Kali installed on my personal Linux-only machine, because I can't help but distro-hop all the time, and I had the same problem there. I was able to rectify it on that machine, but it was an epic journey with lots of loops and twists and turns and bashing my head against the wall, so I don't know what I did to fix it.

My last resort, when all else has proven a failure, is to just gut the `/boot/grub/themes/kali/` directory and put what I want in there. But I'd rather not be ham-fisted about it, and do this properly. There *must* be a way!

Anyway, thanks in advance for helping me solve this otherwise simple problem. I appreciate any help you can give.

---

**TL;DR: No matter what I try, `update-grub` fails to pull my custom theme, even though it takes timeout changes and default OS changes with no problem.**

Comment: Do you have a `GRUB_BACKGROUND` setting somewhere you haven't mentioned?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of; the only mention of `GRUB_BACKGROUND` or anything related to it that I've seen has been the output of `update-grub` showing: `Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png`. If I navigate to to that location, then I can find the .png file in question, but I've not tried changing it via `/etc/default/grub`, as I was assuming that properly setting the theme should take care of the background image as well.

Comment: check for files in `/etc/default/grub.d`

Comment: MY DUDE. You nailed it! (I think; this may be premature.) I did a quick `ls /etc/default/grub.d` and saw a file `kali-themes.conf`. Edited that, and lo and behold, it's still pointing to the wrong theme. Changed it to what I wanted in there, saved the buffer, ran `sudo update-grub` and for the first time, I see the right theme in the `GRUB_THEME` output. Now to reboot and see what I see. Fingers crossed!

Answer (score 2):

### **Bad Solution:**

First backup the original `/boot/grub/themes/kali` directory and then delete the `/boot/grub/themes/kali` directory with `rm -rf /boot/grub/themes/kali` and rename the `/boot/grub/themes/CyberRe` directory to `/boot/grub/themes/kali` with `mv /boot/grub/themes/CyberRe /boot/grub/themes/kali`.
Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRqH36xOSqY

## **New Safe Solution:**

Try removing the `/etc/default/grub.d/kali-themes.cfg` file or rename it to `/etc/default/grub.d/kali-themes.cfg.bak` with `mv /etc/default/grub.d/kali-themes.cfg /etc/default/grub.d/kali-themes.cfg.bak`. I tested this method in a Kali Linux virtual machine.

## Last step for both solutions:

Make sure to run `update-grub` or `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` as root or no effect will take place.